# How to use chmod to hide a folder but allows read/write of the files inside?

Tags: linux, fedora

I just want to disallow the user to view the contents of a folder
but still allows the system/user to have read/write the files inside(when they have direct path)

Is that possible solely by using chmod?

Thanks!

Update: basically there a fedora 14 os where by the account user(not root group) cant view the contents of a folder but he can still access the files in it if he has direct path to the files. Im looking at the root to do a cmod to disallow viewing of the folder content(means user cant double click into the folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Note that for files, bits in `rwx` permission mask mean: `r`=read, `w`=write and `x`=execute. However, for directories, meaning is different, namely: `r`=list directory, `w`=create or delete file in directory, `x`=descend to directory or access files or directories inside of it.

Knowing this, you can create directory structure which has your desired properties.

```
mkdir -p dir/subdir
sudo chmod 111 dir
sudo chmod 775 dir/subdir
```

With this, user will see that `dir` exists, but will not be able to see its contents. However, he will be able to read existing files in `dir`. Also, he will be able to `cd dir/subdir` and have normal access inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:
chmod works like this

```
chmod u+w  pathYouWantToHaveWritePermissionForUser/
chmod u-r  pathYouWantToHaveNOreadPermissionForUser/
```

so for example you have the folder

```
chmod u+w /home/You/save/
chmod u-r /home/You/save/
```

test it with

```
nano /home/You/save/test
```

tip in something andsave the file. If you tip

```
cd /home/You/save/
ls
```

you will not be able to see any file in this directory. But you could read the file test

```
cat test
```

learn more about chmod reading the man page